# Paypal peer to peer transaction with commisson

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to implement a PoC in iOS related with peer to peer payments. I'm in the initial stage of this project and my first idea was the adaptive payments by PayPal.

This is the scenario:

User A (normal user) sells the product.
User B (normal user) buys that product.
Payment made from User B to User A. Commission will be charged automatically from this transaction to me.
Both users are normal users, they are not premium or business. The idea is send money to a friend/familiar.

So my questions are:

1. I checked the Adaptive Payments, there is a "Pay" api which allows pay to receivers with specifying the receiver's email, so I just have to put User B email address for making the payment?
2. How to set charging commission automatically for each transaction?
3. Do we have to authorize the future payment for User A?